# Backbone.js calling a function in a template returns undefined

Tags: function, backbone.js, return-value

I am building a todo application and I have task view which renders a task template and every task has a category chosen by the user. Each task has a CategoryId property. I want to display the category of each task. So I have the following function in the task view:

```
getCategoryName: function (categoryId) {
    return app.Categories.each(function (category) {
        if (categoryId === category.get('CategoryId')) {
            return category.get('CategoryName');
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the task template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="taskTemplate">
<div class="view">
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" <%= Completed ? 'checked' : '' %> />
    <label class="title"><%- Description %></label>
    <section class="info">
        <span class="category"><%- this.getCategoryName(CategoryId) %></span>
    </section>
    <button class="destroy"></button>
</div>
<input class="edit" value="<%- Description %>" />
</script>
```

I call the getCategoryName function and pass the CategoryId of the task. Then the function loops over every category and checks if the passed CategoryId matches an id of a category in the Category collection and then returns the name of the matched category. But no category displays. So I think I'm not returning the name of the category properly. When I console.log it in the callback function it appears in the console but it is not returned.

Do you have any ideas? Could you suggest a solution of this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection.each` doesn't actually return anything; it simply iterates through the items in your collection and executes the callback function for each item. You should use [`Collection.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) instead:

```
getCategoryName: function (categoryId) {

  //find model that matches
  var category = app.Categories.find(function (category) {
    return categoryId === category.get('CategoryId');
  });

  //return the name if found, otherwise returns undefined
  if(category)
    return category.get('CategoryName');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working now, but when I refresh the page sometimes the categories don't appear on the page and other times they appear properly. Could you tell me why is that happening?

Comment: @DimitarUzunov, perhaps sometimes your `app.Categories` collection does not contain any categories to be displayed. Sounds like it maybe a concurrency issue - your Categories `fetch` has not yet completed by the time you try to access it.

Comment: Thanks again. I initialized the categories view before the tasks view and it seems to be working fine now.